# cannot access wp-admin after options table crash and repair

Tags: database, wp-admin

My options table crashed and I did successfully repair it. But now when I login in it redirects to home page with no toolbar, and if I type in /wp-admin I get "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

I have tried the usual, disabling plugins and themes. deleting .htaccess file. Nothing seems to work. I did have a DB backup from a 5 days ago that restores access but many changes were made in that time period, so I am hoping to resolve this issue a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have lost your Admin Privileges. Please run following SQL query and login to WP Admin using newly created WP ADMIN.

```
INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('4', 'demo', MD5('demo'), 'Your Name', 'test@yourdomain.com', 'http://www.test.com/', '2011-06-07 00:00:00', '', '0', 'Your Name');


INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');


INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

New Temporary Admin Details that you can delete later :

> Username : demo
>   Password : demo